# Get and edit state from a component using Vuex. ReferenceError: $store is not defined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm using Vuex to store some data. I'm trying to get a value stored in a *state*, but I don't know how to retrieve it from a component.

I want to load the value inside the ***data*** function from my component shown below. I can save some data succesfully by using `this.$store.dispatch('currentUser/loginUser',this.user)`, but i don't know how to get it.

This is the structure of the Vuex modules:

[image]

The data I want to get is in **loginSettings.js** file. I need to retrieve the *closed* boolean. This is the content inside the file:

```
const state = {
    loginModal:{
        closed: false, // This is the value I need
    }
};
const getters = {};
const actions = {};
const mutations = {};

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

And this is the script tag inside my component.

```
<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      dialog: this.$store.state.loginModal.closed, // This is throwing an error. The error is under this code block
      user:{
          email: "",
          password: ""
      }
    }),
    methods:{
        login(){
            this.$store.dispatch('currentUser/loginUser',this.user)
        }
    }

  }
</script>
```

The error: `Error in data(): "ReferenceError: $store is not defined"`

What is the correct way to make the component's property reactive using Vuex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `this` so it's not looking for the $store variable on the Vue instance, but a $store variable in global scope (which is undefined). Also, with namespaced modules you need to include the module name after `this.$store.state`, so `this.$store.state.loginSettings` is the state object you're trying to access.

However, you want to put store variables in computed, rather than data, so they're updated when they change. Data is only local state and thus it would only initially set your local state to the state in your vuex store and not be reactive.

Thus, this should be your answer:

```
computed: {
  loginModal() {
    return this.$store.state.loginSettings.loginModal
  }
}

// or

computed: {
  closed() {
    return this.$store.state.loginSettings.loginModal.closed
  }
}
```

I would advise against putting local state (whether a component is closed or not seems specific to that component) in your vuex store.

P.S. you can `import { mapState } from 'vuex'` and use it to automatically generate computed properties for you like this:

```
computed: {
  ...mapState('loginSettings', ['loginModal']),
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `this` in the post, but I added it and I'm having the same error. $store is undefined. I'm using `data` because the componente is a Vuetify component. I've just set a computed property the way you said and It's working, but I need to pass the value to data, how can I do that?

Comment: Which Vuetify component? Computed properties can be assigned the same way as data properties.

Comment: A dialog component. I didn't know that was possible! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assigning the `state` value directly to `data` will throw error. You can call it inside `computed` instead.

```
computed:{
  dialog:function(){
    return this.$store.state.loginModal.closed;
  }
}
```

Comment: So what is the correct way to assign the value to `data`? It's a Vuetify component, so the values need to be at `data`

Comment: Functions in `computed` will works same like `data`. I did't tried vuetify before, so can you please try the computed function name instead of `data` in vuetify?

Comment: Throwing this `Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'closed' of undefined"`

Comment: Solved with `return this.$store.state.loginSettings.loginModal.closed`

Comment: This probably not the issue with the computed section. Can you double check the store value and the path.